# ZEND Session Exception

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

after migrating to a new server, emails progammes with a crontab not send more, the script responsible for sending, returns this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'Session must be started before any output has been sent to the browser; output started in /srv/www/assystemps/public/index_cron.php/2' in /srv/www/assystemps/library/Zend/Session.php:443
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/www/assystemps/library/Zend/Session/Namespace.php(143): Zend_Session::start(true)
#1 /srv/www/assystemps/library/Zend/Auth/Storage/Session.php(87): Zend_Session_Namespace->__construct('Zend_Auth')
#2 /srv/www/assystemps/library/Zend/Auth.php(91): Zend_Auth_Storage_Session->__construct()
#3 /srv/www/assystemps/library/Zend/Auth.php(151): Zend_Auth->getStorage()
#4 /srv/www/assystemps/application/AssystempsApplication.php(236): Zend_Auth->getIdentity()
#5 /srv/www/assystemps/public/index_cron.php(121): AssystempsApplication->envoyerMailErreur(Object(Zend_Cache_Exception))
#6 {main}
  thrown in /srv/www/assystemps/library/Zend/Session.php on line 443
```

Comment: add Zend_Session::start(true) to the top of your index_cron.php/2 and see if it fixes it.

Comment: What is the reason of using session in cron task?

Comment: here is the new problem after using Zend_Session :: start ()
  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'Session must be started before Any output has-beens feel to the browser; output started in / srv/www/assystemps/public/index_cron.php/2 'in / srv / www / assystemps / library / Zend / session.php: 443
Stack trace:
# 0 / srv / www / assystemps / public / index_cron.php (33): Zend_Session :: start (true)
# 1 {main}
   thrown in / srv / www / assystemps / library / Zend / session.php on line 443